# Pandas read_csv silently converting and messing up dates and strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv file that has two adjacent columns containing dates like this:

```
29/11/2004 00:00,29/11/2005 00:00,2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

When I read this using read_csv and then write it back to csv using the to_csv method, it gets converted to

```
29/11/2004 00:00,00:00.0,2.0,,,,,,,,
```

I have got two questions about this: Why does it read the first date okay but thinks the second, which seems to have exactly the same format, is 0? And why do the NULLs get converted to empty strings?

Here is the code I am using:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filepath, sep = ",")
df.to_csv("C:\\tmp\\test.csv")
```

Comment: Can you post your pandas version.  Under the .12 release candidate, I get what should be correct.  Both date cols are parsed (you might wand parse_dates=[0, 1]` or do that after reading) and teh NULLs are converted to `NaN`s.

Comment: I am using .11 (and unfortunately cannot upgrade). How does it decide which values to convert to convert to NaNs? What worries me more though is the dates that are going missing...

Comment: Do you have the header line in your csv?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question a bit.  The empty strings are normal for `to_csv`.  Have a look at the `na_rep` argument of `to_csv`.  Just to make sure, When you read the csv in, do you have two columns for the two dates?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the NAs. Yes I do get two columns for the dates when I read the csv. It's just that the second contains these 00:00.0 instead of the actual dates... And waitingkuo, yes I do have headers too.

Comment: Just figured out what was going on - some of the lines contain rubbish, hence the 0s in the dates. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the reason for the missing date. I think it's influenced by other rows.

For the NULL string problem, `keep_default_na` can help you to avoid that:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', keep_default_na=False)
```